# Import not working for slf4j?

Tags: eclipse, import

These imports are not recognized. Any ideas?

import org.slf4j.Logger;

import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

I have tried importing the necessary library but to no avail...

Comment: There isn't enough information here to solve your problem.  Tell us what errors you have, and how your project is set up (where is the slf4j library?  what steps did you take to import it? etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slf4j.jar needs to be on your build path...

From the Package Explorer view, you can drill down to the jar file right click -> Build Path -> Add to build path